# What is the best way to open xaml window   from ViewModle and Wait for DialogResult?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, binding

Currenlty, I'm using as Below.

In xaml,

```
<Button Content="X" Width="33" Height="16" Padding="1,-2,1,0"  
 Command="{Binding ElementName=UserControlName, Path=DataContext.DenyCommand}"
   <Button.CommandParameter>
     <wpfext:UICommandParameter UICommandCallerCallback="{Binding ElementName=UserControlName, Path=UIDenyCallBackCommand}"/>
   </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

In xaml.cs,

```
 public UICommandCallerCallback UIDenyCallBackCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
public UserControlName()
        {

            this.UIDenyCallBackCommand = this.UIAccessDenyCallBack;
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }

 public void UIAccessDenyCallBack(object commandParameter, object callbackData)
        {
            ShowADenyMsgBox();
        }

private void ShowDenyMsgBox()
{
             RightsDenied win = new RightsDenied(); //xaml window
            win.Owner = GetImmediateWindow();
            win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            win.ShowDialog();
}
```

In ViewModel.cs,

```
internal ViewModel()
        {
         this.DenyCommand= new DenyCommand(this.AccessDeny);
        }
public void AccessDeny(ICommandState commandState)
        {
            commandState.InvokeCallerCallback("AccessDenied");
        }

public CommandCallback DenyCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
```

UICommandCallerCallback is declared as below.

```
public delegate void UICommandCallerCallback(object commandParameter, object callbackData);
```

CommandCallback class is as below.

```
public class CommandCallback:ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<ICommandState> executeMethod;

        private readonly Func<ICommandState, bool> canExecuteMethod;

        public CommandCallback(Action<ICommandState> executeMethod)
            : this(executeMethod, null)
        {
        }

        public CommandCallback(Action<ICommandState> executeMethod, Func<ICommandState, bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            if (executeMethod == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");
            }
            this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
            this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }  

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecuteMethod != null ? this.canExecuteMethod((ICommandState)parameter) : true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter","CommandCallback parameter cannot be null");
            }
            if (!(parameter is ICommandState))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("expects a parameter of type ICommandState","parameter");
            }

            ICommandState state = (ICommandState)parameter;
            this.executeMethod.Invoke(state);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working fine if it just to pop up the dialog box, but I want to wait for the result of the  dialog and want to continue  AccessDeny() function. For eg.

```
public void AccessDeny(ICommandState commandState)
            {
               1. processs
               2. open xaml window and wait for the dialogresult. (i.e Yes No or Cancel)
               3. Based on the result, continue processing.

            }
```

What could be the best way to do this work flow? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you send messages from the view model to the view? What if to display the dialog window in the view model? It is the most straight way to do this workflow.

Comment: According to our project workflow, I'm not allowed to do it. If I use the EventHandler, it's able to do as my workflow. But Everytime when the usercontrol is unloaded, I need to detach the event and  it's slow. And, I'm using the winform to popup.

Comment: sry, i meant i used xaml window to pop up, not win form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through **User Interaction Patterns** in [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).